# Replacing authorizeRequests with authorizeHttpRequests will return 401 on calls not explicitly described

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am currently trying to refactor the security configuration after the upgrade to Spring Boot 3.1.1. I am therefore trying to replace all methods marked as deprecated or for removal.

We use different applications for the backend, frontend, and admin interface. I removed some parts of the code to make it readable. Currently, we use a WebSecurityCustomizer to ignore some static resources. Don't mind it. The issue is inside the configure(HttpSecurity http) method. I removed all code (e.g. setting of header data) to have only the code left to reproduce the issue. In the configure method, we set some request matchers on routes for the admin pages, which should be allowed.

1. The old version I am trying to replace is .authorizeRequests(this::authorizeUrlsOld). I am using the ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistry to set request matchers. When I use this code, I can still login to the admin pages and access the regular frontend application.
2. However, when using the new version .authorizeHttpRequests(this::authorizeUrlsNew) all calls that are not explicitally authorized in the method are unauthorized (e.g. api/markets). For this, I replaced the deprecated ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer with AuthorizeHttpRequestsConfigurer, which does not have the ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistry. Therefore, I had to use AuthorizationManagerRequestMatcherRegistry, but it seems to work differently.

How can I get .authorizeHttpRequests(this::authorizeUrlsNew) to work?

**The class SecurityConfiguration:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    private final AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder;
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private final TokenProvider tokenProvider;
    private final GlobalProperties globalProperties;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        try {
            authenticationManagerBuilder
                    .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                    .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new BeanInitializationException("Security configuration failed", e);
        }
    }
    @Bean
    AuthenticationManager customAuthenticationManager(UserDetailsService userDetailsService, PasswordEncoder encoder) {
        return authentication -> {
            var username = String.valueOf(authentication.getPrincipal());
            var password = String.valueOf(authentication.getCredentials());

            var user = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);

            if (!encoder.matches(password, user.getPassword())) {
                throw new BadCredentialsException("Bad credentials");
            }

            if (!user.isEnabled()) {
                throw new DisabledException("User account is not active");
            }

            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, null, user.getAuthorities());
        };
    }
    @Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
        return web -> {
            web.debug(globalProperties.isSecurityDebugEnabled());
            web.ignoring()
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")
                    .requestMatchers("/i18n/**");
        };
    }

    @Bean
    protected SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .authorizeRequests(this::authorizeUrlsOld) //does work
//                .authorizeHttpRequests(this::authorizeUrlsNew) //does not work
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .addFilterBefore(new JWTFilter(tokenProvider), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .build();
    }

    private HttpSecurity authorizeUrlsOld(ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer<HttpSecurity>.ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistry urlRegistry) {
        urlRegistry
                .requestMatchers("api/admin/authenticate").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("api/admin/authenticate/captcha").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("api/admin/**").authenticated();

        return urlRegistry.and();
    }

    private void authorizeUrlsNew(AuthorizeHttpRequestsConfigurer<HttpSecurity>.AuthorizationManagerRequestMatcherRegistry matcherReg) {
        matcherReg
                .requestMatchers("api/admin/authenticate").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("api/admin/authenticate/captcha").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("api/admin/**").authenticated();
    }

}
```

**The class JWTFilter:**

```
public class JWTFilter extends GenericFilterBean {


    private TokenProvider tokenProvider;

    public JWTFilter(TokenProvider tokenProvider) {
        this.tokenProvider = tokenProvider;
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
        String jwt = resolveToken(httpServletRequest);
        if (StringUtils.hasText(jwt) && this.tokenProvider.validateToken(jwt)) {
            Authentication authentication = this.tokenProvider.getAuthentication(jwt);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }

    private String resolveToken(HttpServletRequest request){
        String bearerToken = request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
        if (StringUtils.hasText(bearerToken) && bearerToken.startsWith(JwtConstants.BEARER_PREFIX + " ")) {
            return bearerToken.substring(7, bearerToken.length());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I tried removing the deprecaded methods by new ones.

Comment: Did you read the migration guide?

Comment: Yes, but I did not find anything about a replacement for the removed ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistry.

Comment: why have you built this strange custom security solution? why are you not following common practices and using the built in JWT soltuins that come with spring security? dont you read the docs?

Answer (score 0):

According to `java docs` you should replace old one configuration with next one. It is going to work well.

```
private AuthorizeHttpRequestsConfigurer<HttpSecurity>.AuthorizationManagerRequestMatcherRegistry authorizeUrlsNew(AuthorizeHttpRequestsConfigurer<HttpSecurity>.AuthorizationManagerRequestMatcherRegistry urlRegistry) {
    urlRegistry
        .requestMatchers("api/admin/authenticate").permitAll()
        .requestMatchers("api/admin/authenticate/captcha").permitAll()
        .requestMatchers("api/admin/**").authenticated();

    return urlRegistry;
  }

  @Bean
  protected SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(this::authorizeUrlsNew)
        .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
        .addFilterBefore(new JWTFilter(tokenProvider), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .build();
  }
```

**UPDATE**
Rewrite a little bit the config class remove `authorizeUrlsNew` method and change `configure` method body to something like this:

```
  @Bean
  protected SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(requestMatcherRegistry -> {
                  requestMatcherRegistry.requestMatchers("api/admin/authenticate").permitAll()
                  requestMatcherRegistry.requestMatchers("api/admin/authenticate/captcha").permitAll()
                  requestMatcherRegistry.requestMatchers("api/admin/**").authenticated();
                })
        .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
        .build();
  }
```

Comment: If it will not be able to solve you problem    It mean that it is in another place and I will analyse one more time and will come with an answer about it.

Comment: And also about your problem that before migration not mapped paths into filter chain could be reached and now it is not so.You can change a little bit and add one more thing `requestMatcherRegistry.anyRequest.permitAll()` something like this